# Error when trying to log into Data Explorer, with OpenID, when already logged on with OpenID

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

I get an error when I try to log into [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/faq) (SEDE), with [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID), when already logged on with OpenID. The same occurs when I try to change my OpenID provider.

After looking at the account controller, it looks like it may be a null exception.

After a check has been made to see that the user is not anonymous, the OpenID variable is not null checked before determining whether its UserId property is the same as the CurrentUser Id.

Comment: Oh wow, there's actually several things wrong there...I'll fix things up and assign blame appropriately.

Comment: Ah good, I'm not going mad! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

As you thought, there was the potential for the code to attempt to access a property on a null reference, and [that's been taken care of](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=d8b46153531246d1f4ad3c11e3b3b8eb6a802ddb). Of course, even if it had gotten past that point, you'd have been sent to a 404 page on account of [the return URL being incorrect](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=0de1863f4cc1e065a1a47a207b0924b6ed5fb281) (it was missing an "s").

There was also an [additional problem with an edge case](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=2fe56901f9e89b3651b2523ccb2211e07059eddf) related to user merges that I fixed while I was in there.

The changes have to be pulled into the main repository and then deployed before they'll go live, but hopefully you'll see this fixed on the site soon. Thanks for the report! Now I can start Sunday off feeling like I did something productive by fixing three issues at once, and before getting coffee at that.